# Cut NetCDF files by shapefile

Tags: geojson, netcdf, rasterio, xarray

I have a large dataset of global .nc files and I am trying to clip them to a smaller area. I have this area stored as a .shp file.

I have tried using GDAL from QGIS but needs to do this by converting each variable and I must select each variable and same shape for all files one by one and with 400 files going trough each variable seems not the best idea. Also this returns .tiff files separated and not the .nc file that I am aiming for.

I had this little script but its not doing what I need:

```
import glob
import subprocess
import os

   
Shapefile = 'NHAF-250m.shp'

# Create output directory
OutDir = './Clipped_Rasters/'
if not os.path.exists(OutDir):
    os.makedirs(OutDir)

for Image in ImageList:
    print('Processing ' + Image)

    OutImage = OutDir + Image.replace('.nc', '_BurnedArea_Clipped.tif') # Defines Output Image

    # Clip image
    subprocess.call('gdalwarp -q -cutline /Users/path/to/file/NHAF-250-vector/ -tr 0.25 0.25 -of GTiff NETCDF:'+Image+":burned_area "+OutImage, shell=True)


    print('Done.' + '\n')

print('All images processed.')
```

I have also tried with

```
import geopandas 
import xarray
import rasterio
import glob

shapefile = 'NHAF-250m.shp'

def shapefile_mask(shapefile) -> np.array:
      
    import pyproj

        with fiona.open(shapefile, 'r') as src:
            collection = list(src)
            geometries = []
            for feature in collection:
                geom = shape(feature['geometry'])
                geometries.append(geom)
            mask = geometry_mask(
                geometries,
                out_shape=(1440, 720),
                transform=(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
                all_touched=True,
                invert=True)
            shape_mask = xarray.DataArray(mask , dims=("lon", "lat"))
            return shape_mask
    

    ImageList = sorted(glob.glob('*.nc'))
    print('number of images to process: ', len(ImageList))

shape_mask = shapefile_mask(shapefile)

file_list = sorted(glob.glob('*.nc'))

for file in file_list:
    nc_file = xarray.open_dataset(file)
    # Then apply the mask
    masked_netcdf_file = nc_file.where(shape_mask == True, drop=True)
    # store again as netcdf or do what every you want with the masked array
    masked_netcdf_file.to_netcdf(OutImage)
```

But it is returning `NaN` or `0` for all values in all bands.